# Calling matlab from c++ using cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, makefile, cygwin

I'm working in windows and want to send data from C++ to Matlab. I've gotten the impression this is done most easy creating a makefile. Therefore I've installed cygwin to use the make command.

My makefile is as follows:

```
CXX = g++
CFLAGS = -O3 -I /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/include
LIBS = -L /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/
LIBS2 = -L /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/libmx.lib
LDFLAGS = -leng -lmx

RKspace2d: RKspace2d.o
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) $(LIBS)

RKspace2d.o: RKspace2d.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) $<
# $@ name of the target
# $^ name of all prerequisites with duplicates removed
# $< name of the first prerequisite
```

When I type in "make" in the cygwin terminal, being in the right directory I get the following error:

```
$ make
g++ -o RKspace2d RKspace2d.o -leng -lmx -L /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/MATLAB/R2011a/extern/lib/win64/microsoft/
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -leng
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lmx
collect2: ld returnerede afslutningskoden 1
makefile:8: recipe for target `RKspace2d' failed
make: *** [RKspace2d] Error 1
```

I believe the path is correct since both libeng.lib and libmx.lib are contained in the microsoft folder.

Hope you guys can help
Thomas

Comment: I found a solution, however taking an entirely different route. Using Visual Studio Express and following the following link: http://www.mathworks.se/support/solutions/en/data/1-FWTSV5/index.html
I managed to finally send data from C++ directly to MATLAB